# String input is not accurate

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1024

void run_shell(char * cmd){
        char * str = cmd;
        int size = strlen(str);
        char blank[] = " ";

        char * token = strtok(str, blank);

        char * argv[3];
        int i = 0;
        while(token != NULL){
                argv[i] = token;
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL, blank);
        }

        argv[i] = NULL;

        pid_t pid;

        if((pid = fork()) == 0){
                if(execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0){
                        perror("Invalid Command!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
        }
        else{
                if(waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0){
                        perror("Some Problem Program!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
}

int main(){
        char comand[MAX_LINE];
        char * username;

        printf("Eter your name : ");
        scanf("%s", username);

        while(1){
                char cwd[MAX_LINE];
                getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

                printf("%s %s$ > ", username, cwd);

                fgets(comand, MAX_LINE, stdin);

                printf("\n");
                run_shell(comand);
        }
}
```

I'm making a small shell.
But when I enter a command, the execvp function causes an error.
When I print out argv[], I can see that it has been tokenized without any problems.
It's hard to guess the my code internal movement because I don't know much about the standard input/output.
What's the problem? What should I fix?

Comment: You aren't removing the newline from the input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: user asking to debug it's code

Answer (score 2):

Your program has at least three problems:

- `char * username;` does not initialize `username` to point to anything, so it is uninitialized when `scanf("%s", username);` executes. For a beginner-level program, you can define `username` as `char username[1024];`.
- In `scanf("%s", username);`, the user types some characters and then presses enter/return, which puts a new-line character into the stream. `scanf` reads the non-white-space characters and leaves the new-line character in the stream. Then the later `fgets` reads that new-line character, resulting in a line that is empty except for that character.
- In `fgets(comand, MAX_LINE, stdin);`, `fgets` reads until it finds a new-line character (or the buffer is full). It leaves that new-line character in the buffer, at the end. You should remove it.

Note that none of these is a problem with `execvp`, which shows that the title “The execvp function does not work exactly” is false. When debugging programs, analyze the parts carefully. Do not assume the step where the failure appears is the step that caused the failure. Examine the values of objects (variables) at various points in the program to ensure the steps from beginning to end are proceeding as desired. When examining strings, pay attention to “invisible” characters.